# Get global var from function after $.get() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
var base_url = 'http://api.zxc.loc';
var questions = []; 

function get_question(){
    if(!questions.lenght){
        $.get(base_url + '/api/questions', function(data){
            questions = data;
            console.log('get_question', questions); // GOOD, return [Object, Object ... etc ... ]
        }, 'json')
    } 
    console.log('get_question_2', questions); // BAD return empty array []

    /* var question = questions[0];
    delete questions[0];
    return question; */
}
```

How you can see, in $.get `questions` variable not empty, but after $.get, `questions` is empty!

Why? Thanks

Comment: simple answer you can't do that because ajax requests are asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

This is how AJAX works. In your code `get_question_2` will be logged before `get_question`. Once an ajax call is made, the code proceeds past it (to `get_question_2`). Then one the ajax call is returned, the code inside your function (namely `get_question`) will be executed.

To summarize, the log with `get_question_2` is being called as soon as the ajax call is finished being made and BEFORE the ajax call returns with the data.